# Date select.. wont work

Tags: postgresql

I have a question. When executing the following SQL query:

```
SELECT order_id, orderdatum, plaats
FROM order_row 
INNER JOIN order_row_oneoff ON order_row.order_row_id = order_row_oneoff.order_row_oneoff_id
INNER JOIN orders ON order_row.order_id = orders.ordernr
WHERE orderdatum >= '2015-09-01'
AND orderdatum < '2015-09-05'
AND order_row.product_id = '4118' OR order_row.product_id = '4128' OR order_row.product_id = '4176' AND orders.orderstatus > 98
```

It just selects everything and ignores the date.
But when you remove the second AND clause, it works. Why?

Comment: Is the column orderdatum nullable?

Comment: Which datatype is the column orderdatum?

Comment: show your table definition as well as an expected output

Comment: _side-note : mind your datatype of `order_row.product_id`_

Comment: If `product_id` is a number, then you shouldn't compare it to a string value. `'4128'` is a string, not a number. `4128` is a number

Answer (score 1):

`and` has a higher [*operator precedence*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/static/sql-precedence.html) which means that `and` binds stronger than `or`. Use parentheses to put the conditions together

```
where orderdatum >= '2015-09-01'
and orderdatum < '2015-09-05'
and 
(
   order_row.product_id = '4118' 
   or  order_row.product_id = '4128' 
   or order_row.product_id = '4176'
)
and orders.orderstatus > 98
```

or in your case use `IN`

```
where orderdatum >= '2015-09-01'
and orderdatum < '2015-09-05'
and order_row.product_id in ('4118', '4128' , '4176')
and orders.orderstatus > 98
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a problem in the last and as you should use an `IN` operator instead of `AND`.

```
 product_id IN ('4118', '4128' , '4176')
```